# get minus to positive value in ascending order

Tags: php, sql

I am working in php. I have sql database like :

```
Number
 -5
 -6
 -3
  5
 -1
```

Now, I want to get this data in ascending order so what should I have to do?

Comment: `order by number` at the end of your query.

Comment: What do you know about sql quries?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY Field_Name ASC
```